# Airflow DAG is running but tasks not getting executed

Tags: python, task, command-line-interface, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using Airflow 1.10.2 forked from the popular [puckel airflow docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/puckel/docker-airflow) and using the CLI to operate it reading the [documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/cli.html). I had created a DAG which is getting executed successfully when I trigger it through the UI. But when I use the command line to trigger the DAG, the DAG status becomes RUNNING but the tasks are never executed.

For references of the images below, the ID of the DAG is `xcom_4_modules_ver_5`

After running the DAG through a scheduled process and triggering manually through the UI, I executed `airflow list_dag_runs xcom_4_modules_ver_5` on CLI to check the status of DAG run. The DAG was successfully executed and wrote the expected output in log file. This corresponds to ID 1 and 2.

[image]

However, after executing the command `airflow trigger_dag -sd /usr/local/airflow/airflow/dags/ -r CLI-RUN-TEST xcom_4_modules_ver_5` to trigger the DAG from the UI, the status is forever RUNNING. Corresponds to ID 3 in the image below.

[image]

I went to the tree view in UI to realise that no component has been executed for very long.

[image]

The first two green columns corresponds to run ID 1 and 2 whereas the third column maps to run ID 3.

The `airflow scheduler` and `airflow webserver` are on.

Would request Airflow masters here to suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer people seek, nor the most applicable one but I'll post it anyway. Airflow version 2 has solved a lot of these DAG runtime hiccups and scheduler jams for us. Prior, with version 1.10 these bugs happened more often than not but Airflow 2 has way less and smaller bugs in comparison. Still wouldn't say it's a perfect piece of software though.

Apache has good instructions to follow if you decide to upgrade as well: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-from-1-10/index.html

If not for the feature updates, the improvement in stability in my experience is already worth it after a year or so.